# Spoonacular API integration with Python

Tags: python, api, spoonacular

```
def getRecipeByIngredients():
    payload = {
        'fillIngredients': False,
        'ingredients': ingredients,
        'limitLicense': False,
        'number': 5,
        'ranking': 1
    }

    api_key = os.environ['api_key']

    endpoint = "https://spoonacular-recipe-food-nutrition-v1.p.mashape.com/recipes/findByIngredients"


    headers={
        "X-Mashape-Key": "mashape key",
        "X-Mashape-Host": "mashape host"
    }

    r = requests.get(endpoint, params=payload, headers=headers)
    results = r.json()
    title = results[0]['title']
    print(title)
```

I am having trouble accessing the title of the recipe when searching for recipes by ingredients using the Spoonacular API. I've followed all the instructions on the page and made sure I'm getting to the title correctly, however when I search for the recipe nothing is outputted besides the GET request. Any ideas?

Comment: Can you specify me, what is `ingredients` and second where are you using `api_key` ?

Answer (score 2):

It looks like your code is mostly correct.

Here are the necessary changes:

- Make sure the `ingredients` variable is given a value
- Make sure `api_key` is given as the value for the `X-Mashape-Key` header

I've made the relevant changes to your code below:

```py
import requests

def getRecipeByIngredients(ingredients):
    payload = {
        'fillIngredients': False,
        'ingredients': ingredients,
        'limitLicense': False,
        'number': 5,
        'ranking': 1
    }

    api_key = "your-api-key"

    endpoint = "https://spoonacular-recipe-food-nutrition-v1.p.mashape.com/recipes/findByIngredients"


    headers={
        "X-Mashape-Key": api_key,
        "X-Mashape-Host": "mashape host"
    }

    r = requests.get(endpoint, params=payload, headers=headers)
    results = r.json()
    title = results[0]['title']
    print(title)

getRecipeByIngredients('apple')
```

If you're interested, I've written a Python package that wraps the Spoonacular API and makes it easy to access each of its endpoints. The package is [available on GitHub](https://github.com/johnwmillr/SpoonacularAPI).